# События на сайте

Tags: socket.io

Хочу перевести сайт на Web 2.0 т.е. любые события без перезагрузки страницы. 
В реальном времени выводить:

1) всплывающие окна (о новой покупке, сообщениях, уведомлениях...);
 2) отправка форм и обновление блоков, без перезагрузки страницы;
 3) сделать диалоги, как в современных социальных сетях;
 4) прочее.

Посоветовали такую штуку, как Socket.io, будто он будет пушить сообщения на сайт и выводить их.

Подойдет ли Socket.io для моих требований или использовать AJAX? Как подружить Socket.io с PHP? Может, кто-то сталкивался с таким, дайте толчок в правильном направлении. Спасибо.

Comment: > Как подружить Socket.io с PHP? 
Напрямую - плохая идея, но если вам нужно сделать общение готового движка с пользователями посредством socket.io, то можно заморочиться с rabbitmq или другим способом общения между php процессом и node/ryby/python/другой удобной для асинхронного программирования средой.

Comment: Т.е. что же мне сделать? AJAX?

Comment: Всё зависит от бюджета проекта.

Comment: Т.е. бюджета? Хочется просто научится, практика для саморазвития. :)

Comment: ну опять же, сколько вы готовы на это потратить времени, что именно хочется... Я просто высказал свое мнение, подвержденное опытом, - асинхронный сервер на php писать не стоит. Сделайте коммуникацию с другим приложением.

Comment: Готов потратить не более месяца на запил этой фичи. А как тогда организовать хоть что-то подобное? Хочется максимальной скорости и оптимизации. А если еще прямее сказать, то: "хочу уведомления как вконтакте", "хочу диалоги как вконтакте"

Comment: Ну вот один из вариантов (предположим, что сайт на php у вас уже есть):

 * перед всем nginx, отправляет запросы к php php, статику к статике, сокетные url к приложению на ноде;
 * php  работает как обычно, но сессию храним в какой-нибудь бд, доступной и php, и ноде;
 * нода проверяет доступ юзера по заголовкам сессии и забирает эти данные из этой общей базы, создает сокеты и рвет их, если юзер сделал logout.

За месяц можно справиться, если знаете основы js.

Answer (score 1):

Все, что вы хотите реализовать, можно легко сделать на MeteorJS.
https://www.meteor.com/

Только к PHP этот framework никакого отношения не имеет.
Сделать такой проект на PHP можно, но это займет у вас много времени на отладку.